# Can someone explain to me how 'sigaction' works?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm having difficulties understanding the way `sigaction()` works.

In `<signal.h>`, sigaction is defined as

```
int sigaction(int sig, const struct sigaction *act, struct sigaction *oact)
```

But `sigaction` is also defined in `bits/sigaction.h` as a structure. I'm confused here, can a struct in C be made callable?

Can someone please give me a brief explanation on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is called `sigaction`, the structure is called `struct sigaction`. Functions and structures exist in different namespaces in C. It is similar to the way you can do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct x {
        int x;
};

static int
x(struct x *x) {
        return x->x;
}

int
main(void) {
        struct x y;
        /* But not "struct x x" as we want to call the "x" function below. */

        y.x = 1;
        printf("%d\n", x(&y));
        return 0;
}
```

And the compiler can sort out which `x` is which by the various namespaces. But this example is rather excessive and would get you some dirty looks if you did something like this in real life.